# Как удалить обернутый обработчик события?

Tags: javascript, события, listener

Я переопределил метод **addEventListener** таким образом, чтобы он добавлял обертку к функции-обработчику:

```
    var freeze = false;
    var _addEventListener = EventTarget.prototype.addEventListener;
    EventTarget.prototype.addEventListener = function(type, fn){
        var self = this;
        var wrapper = function(){
            if( !freeze ){
                fn.apply(self, arguments);
            }
            else{
                // TODO: Действия при выключенных обработчиках
            }
        };
        var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments).slice(2);
        _addEventListener.apply(this, [type, wrapper].concat(args));
    };
```

Подскажите, как мне теперь отключить обернутый обработчик заданного события?
Что нужно передавать в **removeEventListener**?

Comment: Осмелюсь предположить, что в `removeEventListener` передать нужно тип события и функцию, которую нужно удалить, в соответствующей последовательности. Ссылка на описание [removeEventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/removeEventListener)

Comment: К сожалению, не выходит. Я в `removeEventListener` отправляю _аналогичную_ (также обернутую) функцию, но обработчик не снимается... Вероятно получаются **две разные** функции, а не одна и та же.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Чтобы правильно удалить обработчик при помощи `removeEventListener`, необходимо сохранить обертку в специальном хранилище [WeakMap](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/WeakMap) с ключом, равным изначальной функции-обработчику.

```
var fnMap = new WeakMap();

var _addEventListener = EventTarget.prototype.addEventListener;
EventTarget.prototype.addEventListener = function(type, fn){
    var wrapper = function(){
        if( !freeze ){
            fn.apply(self, arguments);
        }
        else{
            // TODO: Действия при выключенных обработчиках
        }
    };

    fnMap.set(fn, wrapper);

    var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments).slice(2);
    _addEventListener.apply(this, [type, wrapper].concat(args));
};

var _removeEventListener = EventTarget.prototype.removeEventListener;
EventTarget.prototype.removeEventListener = function(type, fn){
    var wrapper = fnMap.get(fn);
    // ...
    _removeEventListener.apply(this, [type, wrapper].concat(args));
}
```